# WPF Listbox Selection problem

Tags: wpf, listbox, selection

I have a strange problem with a listbox. I added only the listbox and a button which adds items to the listbox. If I click an item in the listbox it seems to have some strange multi selection mode on or something... i recorded a short screen cast, see for your self:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zV4424ipNEA
any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: Do you hold `Ctrl` button pressed? :)

Comment: nope.. but i will reboot and check, maybe something hangs...

Comment: I rebooted without luck.. it's really a strange problem :(

Comment: This should show some code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a known issue, as all those strings are the same the selection gets confused because they all are essentially the same object. If you create two identical strings in .NET it does not necessarily create a new one but may reuse the first instance, i am not an expert on this though.

Either wrap the strings in a class (make them the `Content` of a `ListBoxItem` for example) or make sure the values are unique.

Comment: you are my hero :) the list box will of course have different items.

Comment: Glad that helped! You can give heroes upvotes by the way, not that i'd want any :D

Comment: Having tried this initially without success, I have to flag a comment by @Oliver Hanappi in a similar thread which states that you cannot have Equals/GetHashCode overrides on your wrapper class that implement value equality, which I was, and now am not.